# Java objects compare with null cases?

Tags: java

Is there any ready implementation of method

```
public static boolean equals(Object o1, Object o2) {
   return o1==null && o2==null || o1!=null && o2!=null && o1.equals(o2);
}
```

somewhere in JRE/JDK?

Comment: You've just implemented it.

Comment: What would it mean if there was? You want a standalone equals you'd have to call as a utility?

Comment: Please note that JDK includes the JRE..

Comment: You could do it a little more compact with ```o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2)``` but not everybody likes using '?'. On the other hand, with JDK 7 Objects is the better way as @niels-bech-nielsen pointed in his answer.

Comment: The logic can be shortened to `return (o1 == o2) || (o1 != null && o1.equals(o2));` :) which is what is implemented in JDK as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are on JDK 7..

```
Objects.equals(a,b)
```

That's `Objects` with an `s`, which is in `java.util`, as in the utility library for objects, similar to `Collections` with an `s` and `Arrays` with an `s`.